# Why is there a gap between these two elements?

Tags: html, css, svg

So I'm learning how to use SVG and this keeps happening and I can't figure out why. As well the title moves with it such as shown below. This gap keeps happening between these 2 elements and I searched online but can't figure out what's wrong.

Example Picture: [The Gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zc0I.png)

Here's my code as well if it helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<html>

<head>

<style>

@font-face {
    font-family: caviarplain;
    src: url(fonts/CaviarDreams.ttf);
}


span.topbar {
  display: inline;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
  }



 </style>
  </head>

<body>



<span class="topbar">
<a href="About.html" title="About">
   <svg>
    <text x="0" y="50" font-family="caviarplain" font-size="25">
        About
    </text>
   </svg>
</a>
</span>

<span class="topbar">
<a href="Homepage.html" title="Homepage">
<svg>
    <text x="0" y="50" font-family="caviarplain" font-size="25">
       Home
    </text>
</svg>
</a>
</span> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip Jaquez I'll go and edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of svg has default width and height you should give to width in css like this

```
    svg{
        width:50px;
    }
```